# Custom ToolPart is not Display in Custom Properties section with styling

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, toolpart

I create custom toolpart in custom webpart that tool property bind data in dropdown list.but is not display properly..
It look like below

[image]

but I want to display this Custom categories with "+" button.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following custom properties:

```
[WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]    //available in both Personalization and Customization mode.
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[FriendlyNameAttribute("Header")]                   //will be displayed to user
[Description("Sets webpart title")]                   //will be displayed on tooltip
[WebBrowsable(true)]                                   //hide or show
[Category("UI Configuration")]                        //category name where to be shown
[XmlElement(ElementName = "String")]
public string WebPartHeader
{
 get;
 set;
}
```

The result:
[image]

This is a reference about Creating a WebPart with a custom ToolPart properties:

https://maulikdhorajia.blogspot.sg/2012/01/sharepoint-custom-toolpart-properties.html